# シェルスクリプト内で、パスにawkをかける方法を教えてください

Tags: linux, bash, shellscript, awk

シェルスクリプト内で、引数に指定したパスの一番下のディレクトリを取得したいと思い、以下のように書きました。

■test.sh

```sh
#! /bin/sh

myfol=`awk -F"/"  '{print $NF} ${1}`
mylog=2016_${myfol}.txt
touch ${mylog}
```

■実行時

```
test.sh /var/log/aaa_sever
```

■エラーメッセージ

> awk : 警告 : コマンドライン引数  `/var/log/aaa_server`はディレクトリです：スキップされました

awkがだめなのかと考え、sedに変更してみても、やはり同じようなエラーが出てしまいます。
2016_aaa_server.txtというファイルを作成するにはどのようにしたらよいでしょうか。

Comment: 2016_aaa_server.txt というファイルはどこに作りたいのでしょうか。このままえでは、/var/log/aaa_server というディレクトリを指定していますが、それはそれとしてまるっと無視してカレントディレクトリにファイルを作ってしまいます。もしかして、 /var/log/aaa_server/2016_aaa_server.txt というファイルを作りたいのでしょうか。また、maylogに代入している `${myfile}` は `${myfol}` の typo でしょうか。

Comment: すみません、カレントディレクトリにファイルを作成したいです。

Comment: `awk` の使い方が間違っています。`awk` のコマンドライン引数は、基本的には、各種オプション、awk スクリプト、そして入力するファイルです。ディレクトリ名は渡せません。各種コマンドやスクリプトは、あなたのやりたいこと、あなたの渡したものが何なのかを、あなたの気持ちを汲んで解釈するなんて器用なことはしせん。マニュアルを読むなどして、コマンドがどういったコマンドライン引数をどのように受け取るのかを知りましょう。

Answer (score 3):

awk に拘らないのであれば、 basename というコマンドが正にパスの最後の部分のみを取り出してくれるコマンドです。ちなみに、対となるコマンドとして、最後の部分以外を取り出す、 dirname というコマンドもあります。

```
myfol=`basename "${1}"`
```

awk を使うのであれば、加工する文字列を、awkが標準入力から読み込めるようにしてみて下さい。echo で表示させたテキストをパイプで繋いで読み込むのが簡単です。 sed を使う場合も同様です。

```
myfol=`echo -n "${1}" | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'`
```

Comment: 教えていただいたやり方で解決しました。本当にありがとうございます。sed,awkに渡す時はechoを使うのですね。とても勉強になりました。